# Android - How to print from an Android device?

Tags: android

I want to have a print feature in my Android application.Also,my application may cater to varied users and I do not want them to do any pc configurations for the same.Also,I do not know what type of printers they may use.Kindly provide me some knowledge in this regard or how to implement this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Android SDK has no Printer Api still. we have to use Third party apis best of them is Google Cloud Print.

You can simply pass pdf file to PrintDialogActivity which in sample..., it will be printed from any where but before that your printer must be registered with Google Cloud  Servers.

Go through below links

Google cloud print Sample:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android

How to register:
http://support.google.com/cloudprint/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1686197&p=mgmt_classic

How it works:
http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/howitworks.html

Help:
http://support.google.com/cloudprint/?hl=en&p=mkt_support_faq

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android

Comment: Thanks!!Also do you have any idea if wifi and bluetooth printing are possible on Android

Comment: You may use cloud printing new API for KitKat that allows Wifi direct printing, or web base printing. There still not much documentation beside http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iub67ic87KI and https://developer.android.com/training/printing/custom-docs.html

Answer (score 7):

Great news!

> In Android 4.4 (API level 19) and higher, the framework provides
>   services for printing images and documents directly from Android
>   applications.

https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html

Comment: For API < 19 [Google Cloud Print](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android) is still the go-to option.