# How to implement print functionality in android?

Tags: android, printing

I am developing an email application. In my application I want to provide print option for printing mails. Here I want to connect to printer through WiFi or LAN.

How to implement this functionality?

Comment: Have you ever searched anything before?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10497298/792232 check this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - How to print from an Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496958/android-how-to-print-from-an-android-device)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. He is asking for "wi-fi or LAN", so I'm guessing in an offline context, not using Google Cloud print.

Answer (score 0):

Share your document with something that *can* print (e.g. Cloud Print).

Answer (score 0):

[Google Cloud Print](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/?hl=en) is the way to go

From their site

> Google Cloud Print enables any application (web, desktop, mobile) on
>   any device to print to any printer.
>
> Applications submit print jobs to the service via the web-based common
>   print dialog or API offered by the service. Google Cloud Print then
>   sends the print job to the selected printer which the user has
>   previously registered with the service. A new class of Cloud Ready
>   printers connect directly to the service and offers the best user
>   experience. Non-cloud printers connect to the service via a software
>   connector.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I searched in the google about it. Is it open source?

Comment: Open source I doubt, but free to use, yes of now

Comment: What if you wanted to do this only in a LAN environment, ie, no internet connection?