# How to implement Print feature like Gmail in Android

Tags: android, pdf, printing, google-cloud-print

I want to create Printing options like GMail, how can i achieve my goal, please advice, Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: what exactly you want to print?

Comment: I have a text to print, if Print options wants to give pdf format, i can send pdf file as well

Comment: so you basically need to know `how to print in Android`, not `like Gmail in Android`, right?

Comment: I want the same like GMail

Comment: then you have to explain, how exactly is `same like GMail`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - How to print from an Android device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496958/android-how-to-print-from-an-android-device)

Comment: I saw the PrintDialogActivity and it opens Google Chrome not like GMail

Comment: then you should decompile Gmail, and see how it does that.

Comment: or explain how you want it to be, what exactly `same like GMail` means

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **print any existing pdf file** than you can use this **code**, i have also implement this
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Printing

First initialize

```
 private PrintManager mgr = (PrintManager) context.getSystemService(PRINT_SERVICE);
```

And **path** is your **Pdf** file path in your phone sdcard

```
 print("PDF", new PdfDocumentAdapter(context, new File(path)), new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());

 private PrintJob print(String name, PrintDocumentAdapter adapter,
                       PrintAttributes attrs) {
    context.startService(new Intent(context, PrintJobMonitorService.class));
    return (mgr.print(name, adapter, attrs));
}
```

Comment: Does this code have a minSDK limit? Does it works all the way back to API 14?

Comment: No this have API limit, 21 and above

Comment: Though so ><
They are workaround for lower Api levels but so far Print manager is much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

See the [android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html) on how to print. This is what Gmail is using (Print Spooler system app).
In your case, you may want to use the "[Print an html document](https://developer.android.com/training/printing/html-docs.html)". It requires API 19+ though.